# Updating boolean value with cloud firestore in Vue

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new to both Vue and Firebase. So I'm trying to implement a very simple library app with both. Here you can create a book object with title, author and whether it's been 'read' or not(Always false by default). Each component has a checkbox to update the value of the 'read' attribute. However, the updating function only updates the value once, and I'm expecting it to change every time the checkbox changes. What am I doing wrong?

This is the template and the function in App.vue :

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <Header />
    <AddBook v-on:add-book="addBook" />
    <Books v-bind:books="books" v-on:del-book="deleteBook" v-on:update-book="updateBook" />
  </div>
</template>
```

```
updateBook(id, book) {
  console.log(book);
  db.collection("books")
    .doc(id)
    .update({
      read: !book.read,
    })
    .then(() => {
      console.log("Book successfully updated!");
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error("Error updating book: ", error);
    });
}
```

And I'm passing the data with $emit from Book.vue :

```
<template>
  <div class="book" v-bind:class="{ 'is-read': book.read }">
    <p>{{ book.title }}</p>
    <p>{{ book.author }}</p>
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      v-on:change="$emit('update-book',book.id, book)"
      v-bind:checked="book.read"
    />
    <button @click="$emit('del-book', book.id)">x</button>
  </div>
</template>
```

If anyone could help me I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: I'm unclear.  What behavior are you expecting that's different than what you're observing?  Please edit the question to provide more details.

Comment: In the `updateBook()`method, what does write `console.log(book);`?

Comment: I assume you're trying to get one value only?

Comment: The behaviour I'm expecting is that whenever the checkbox changes, the 'read' attribute changes from false to true or the other way around. But this only happens once. The console.log(book) writes:  `{__ob__: Observer}
book: (...)
id: (...)
__ob__: Observer {value: {…}, dep: Dep, vmCount: 0}
get book: ƒ reactiveGetter()
set book: ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)
get id: ƒ reactiveGetter()
set id: ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)
__proto__: Object`

Comment: When providing addition information, it's preferred to edit the question to add the details rather than burying it in comments. There is an edit link at the bottom of the question.

Comment: That's what I just did. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed my error. The db has an object which has an id and a book object inside. I was calling the object.read, and this was undefined. I should have set it to object.book.read.

```
updateBook(object) {
  db.collection("books")
    .doc(object.id)
    .update({
      read: !object.book.read,
    })
    .then(() => {
      console.log("Book successfully updated!");
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error("Error updating book: ", error);
    });
}
```